# How to parse a json in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am getting the values of some datatypes in umbraco to my MVC view in cshtml I am getting a result in JSON how will I parse the JSON to bind it to a drop down list. What are the possible methods to do this. I have installed NetonSoft JSON in project also

```
if (home.GetProperty("residentsLogin") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(home.GetPropertyValue("residentsLogin")))
    {
        var residentslog = home.GetPropertyValue("residentsLogin");
}
```

[image]

My JSON is in the corresponding format

```
[
  {
    "name": "Property1",
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "target": "_blank",
    "icon": "icon-link"
  },
  {
    "name": "Property2",
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "target": "_blank",
    "icon": "icon-link"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok will edit my question more briefly

Answer (score 1):

Working code should look like this:

```
    public class MyJsonObject
    {
        public string name{get;set;}
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string target { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }


var residentslog = @"[
    {
    'name': 'Property1',
    'url': 'http://www.google.com',
    'target': '_blank',
    'icon': 'icon-link'
    },
    {
    'name': 'Property2',
    'url': 'http://www.google.com',
    'target': '_blank',
    'icon': 'icon-link'
    }
]";
    List<MyJsonObject> myJsonObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyJsonObject>>(residentslog);   

    ViewBag.MySelectList = new SelectList(myJsonObjectList, "name", "url");
```

Comment: should I install or add any script file to get the keyword JsonConvert

Comment: You should add reference `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: I have implemented this code in my view but cannot generate a desired output. Is there anything that I should do for perfecton